# Excel VBA code how to add text to specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

Length of all cells in a specific columns has to be 6 characters. If not, I have to add 0 in the beginning of each cell until cell length =6. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Comment: Note that this can be done without VBA if you accept that the result is put in a different column. You can then hide the original column. If there is a choice, then it is almost always better to do such things with in-cell formulas than with VBA.

Comment: Yes, its even greater method. What formula should I use?

Comment: Assuming that the column you wish to reformat is in column `A` and starts in row `1` you could write in cell `B1` the following formula and copy it down `=RIGHT("000000"&MID(A1,1,6),6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample for column **C**:

```
Sub Make6()
    Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    bry = Array("000000", "00000", "0000", "000", "00", "0", "")
    Dim N As Long, v As String, L As Long
    Set r1 = Range("C:C")
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r2 = Range("C1:C" & N)
    Set r3 = Range("C" & N + 1 & ":C" & Rows.Count)

    r1.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each r In r2
        v = r.Value
        L = Len(v)
        If L < 6 Then
            r.Value = bry(L) & v
        End If
    Next r
    r3.Value = "000000"

End Sub
```

It will fix ALL cells in column **C**.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cont As String


Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Your Sheet

With sh
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Coloumn A

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
        Do Until Len(Cells(i, 1)) = 6   'Coloumn A
            cont = Cells(i, 1)          'Coloumn A
            Cells(i, 1) = "0" & cont    'Coloumn A
        Loop
    Next i

End With
```

Does this work for you? You only have to edit the coloumn that you want to check, you could use a TextBox for that.